# 2-D Inverse Fourier transform of $\exp(-k a^2)/k^2$ with $k = \sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-transform

**First version:**
How to calculate the inverse Fourier transform of $\exp(-k a^2)/k^2$ with $k = \sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}$ and a parameter $a$ ?
Thank you.
I have no idea for this.

**Second version:**
I means to calculate the following integral
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty } \int\limits_{-\infty }^{\infty }  \mathrm{exp} (-i k_1 x_1 - i k_2 x_2) \mathrm{exp} (-a^2\sqrt{{k_1}^2+{k_2}^2} )/({k_1}^2+{k_2}^2) \mathrm{d} k_1 \mathrm{d} k_2
$$
Many thanks for the comments and help! (I have learned how to input formulas using Latex (https://www.latexlive.com/) now, sorry for the ambiguous first version)

Comment: Do you want$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\Bbb R^2}\frac{\exp(-ka^2+ik\cdot x)}{k^2}d^2k=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp(-ka^2+ikx\cos\theta)}{k}dk,$$or do you define the inverse FT with some other convention?

Comment: Thank you. I mean a Inverse FT in O-x1x2 plane within rectangular coordinate system, k1 for x1, and k2 for x2.

Comment: Yes, but do you define an inverse FT with $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\exp(ik\cdot x)d^2k$, $\int\exp(2\pi ik\cdot x)d^2k$, or some other operator?

Comment: Yes, I use the first one. Thank you.

Comment: Please see Eq. 5-7 in this paper [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241069465_Two-Dimensional_Fourier_Transforms_in_Polar_Coordinates)

Comment: The integral diverges (at $k=0\,\, I\sim\int_0\frac {1}{k} dk$). But we can get a closed form. Using $\frac{1}{k}=\int_0 ^\infty e^{-kt}dt$
$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\infty\frac{\exp(-ka^2+ikx\cos\theta)}{k}dk=\int_0^\infty dt\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^\infty e^{-k(a^2+t-ix\cos\theta)}dk$$
Integrating over $k$ and $\theta$ (making the change $z=\tan\theta$)
$$=2\int_0^\infty dt\int_0^{\pi}\frac{(a^2+t)d\theta}{(a^2+t)^2+x^2\cos^2\theta}=2\pi\int_{a^2}^\infty\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+x^2}}\to\infty$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Thank you. $z=\mathrm{tan} (\theta )$?

Comment: Yes, the substitution $z=\tan(\theta)$ in the last line